# lightbox with title above image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using magnific-popup for a lightbox gallery which I have working fine but I need to have the image title above the image and the description below the image.

the link I have when clicking the image for a larger view is:

```
<a <a class="test-popup-link" href="<?php echo $image_large['sizes']['gallery-main']; ?>" title="<?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?>" data-description="<?php echo the_sub_field('description'); ?>">
```

which has the title and data-description but I need to somehow seperate these.

I also have this:

```
$('.popup-container').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  type: 'image',
  mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
  gallery: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  image: {
    titleSrc: function(item) {
      return item.el.attr('title') + '<p>' + item.el.attr('data-description') + '</p>';
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a way of separating the title and description?